# Why is my ASP C# WCF Service not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am working on a project for school and I need to create a WCF service that I can use in my original solution.

I created the service by going to File -> New Project -> WCF Service Application (add to solution) and then I added the service reference by right clicking References under Assignment8 solution and new reference.  Then I discovered services in the solution and added the Product service.

I am currently getting the **error:**

> 'Assignment8.Product.ProductClient' does not contain a definition for 'UpdateProduct' and no extension method 'UpdateProduct' accepting a first argument of type 'Assignment8.Product.ProductClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The error occurs in UpdateProduct.aspx.cs on the line with the if statement in the Button1_Click method.  What am I doing wrong?

Here are my files:

**IProduct.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace ProductService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IProduct
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        [OperationContract]
        Boolean UpdateProduct(int productID, string productName, string productDescription, decimal productPrice, decimal productCost);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Product.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ProductService.Product" CodeBehind="Product.svc.cs" %>
```

**Product.svc.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace ProductService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Product : IProduct
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }

        public bool UpdateProduct(int productID, string productName, string productDescription, decimal productPrice, decimal productCost)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**UpdateProduct.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Product.ProductClient orderproxy = new Product.ProductClient())
            {
                if(orderproxy.UpdateProduct(Request.QueryString["ID"], txtProductName.Text, txtProductName.Text, txtProductDescription.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtProductPrice.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txtProductCost.Text))){
                    Response.Redirect("~/ProductList.aspx");
                } else {
                    lblStatus.Text = "The product could not be updated.";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition of UpdateProduct takes only 5 arguments but in your call you are passing 6 arguments